# Docker hello-world container won't start on Windows Server 2016 on top of VMWare

Tags: docker, windows-server-2016, containers, mcafee

I've been trying to get Docker installed and running on a Windows VM to get a better understanding of the runtime for downstream work, and I'm running into the issues starting the `hello-world` container.

### Environment:

- VMWare virtual hardware:

  - 4 GB RAM
  - Intel Xenon CPU (2 cores)
- Windows Server 2016 Standard (Version 1607)
- Some antivirus and firewall considerations (I'm getting more info on those)

Output from `docker version`:

```
Client:
 Version:      17.06.2-ee-6
 API version:  1.30
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   e75fdb8
 Built:        Mon Nov 27 22:46:09 2017
 OS/Arch:      windows/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.06.2-ee-6
 API version:  1.30 (minimum version 1.24)
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   e75fdb8
 Built:        Mon Nov 27 22:55:16 2017
 OS/Arch:      windows/amd64
 Experimental: false
```

### What's worked:

- Downloading and installing the Docker package following [the script install deploy path from docs.docker.com](https://docs.docker.com/install/windows/docker-ee/#use-a-script-to-install-docker-ee)
- Starting the Docker daemon itself.
- Downloading the layers for the `hello-world` image.

### What hasn't:

Running any container.  We've tried a few:

- `hello-world:nanoserver`
- `hello-world:latest`
- `microsoft/nanoserver:latest`
- `microsoft/windowsservercore:latest`

### What have I already tried (with no success):

- Relaxing our Group Policy Settings
- Enabling the Hyper-V Windows Optional Component

### What actually happens:

When I attempt to start a container using `docker run {container-name-here}`, PowerShell hangs for a substantial amount of time (a couple of minutes) and prints the following message:

```
C:\Program Files\docker\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: container
    {container-id-here} encountered an error during Start: failure in a
    Windows system call: This operation returned because the timeout
    period expired. (0x5b4).
```

In the `docker events` log, I get the following messages at the same time:

```
2018-04-18T09:36:27.881680400-04:00 container create {container-id-here} (image=hello-world:nanoserver, name=confident_ardinghelli)
2018-04-18T09:36:27.883680800-04:00 container attach {container-id-here} (image=hello-world:nanoserver, name=confident_ardinghelli)
2018-04-18T09:36:28.753726900-04:00 network connect {network-id-here} (container={container-id-here}, name=nat, type=nat)
2018-04-18T09:40:21.373395500-04:00 network disconnect {network-id-here}(container={container-id-here}, name=nat, type=nat)
```

We get the timeout message between the `network connect` and the `network disconnect`.

The references I've found in my searching ([here](https://github.com/StefanScherer/dockerfiles-windows/issues/203), and [here](https://mdaslam.wordpress.com/tag/docker-windows-server-2016-this-operation-returned-because-the-timeout-period-expired-0x5b4/)) indicate that this may be an antivirus issue, but I've been unable to find any documentation on how to confirm that it's an antivirus problem or which antivirus component may be the problem short of disabling the antivirus and trying again. I'm working on getting with the folks that have access to that part of the system and trying again, I'll update with results.

## So, what am I actually asking?

- Has anyone else seen this or a similar issue before?  What steps were you able to take to diagnose the root cause, and what ended up being the issue in your case?
- Are there any other Docker or Windows logs I should be looking at to better diagnose the cause of the issue?
- Any other "shots in the dark" we should try?  We're running out of ideas after we get through our security debug.

## Update (2018-4-20):

We spoke with the security team, and went through enabling and disabling various antivirus components.  When we turned off McAfee Host IPS (HIPS), we were able to start any of our containers, as expected.  When we turn it back on, the containers break again!  We've found an alert in the HIPS log for a denied registry read that matches up time-wise with our debug session, and we've traced that registry access back to the docker.exe process using [Process Monitor from Microsoft Sysinternals](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon).  Looks like we have our culprit!

I'll report back after we add a whitelist entry for the rule and confirm the fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The solution

In this case, McAfee Host Intrusion Prevention Service (HIPS) was the issue preventing Docker from running.  McAfee HIPS provides a number of intrusion monitoring rules, and one of them preventing unwarranted registry access was getting triggered.  We disabled the rule for `docker.exe`, and it's been smooth sailing since!

### Steps to debug

We identified this by debugging Docker by disabling individual security components until docker was able to function, and then re-enabling everything except HIPS to verify that nothing else was interfering.  We then re-enabled HIPS, reproduced the issue, and checked the HIPS logs for an alert that matched up time-wise.

The Docker CLI was attempting to access the following registry keys and being denied access:

```
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\docker.exe
```

We used [Process Monitor from Microsoft Sysinternals](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to verify the registry access was associated with docker.exe.

Finally, we disabled that HIPS rule for `docker.exe`, and now we can successfully run arbitrary containers.

Comment: So you are saying that you where able to install docker for windows and run windows (not Linux) containers like the microsoft/nanoserver:latest on a Windows 2016 VM that runs on VMWare hypervisor?

Comment: Hey @ares!  Yes, I was able to get windows containers running on the VM.  We ended up having to resolve the HIPS issue I mentioned in my comment, but we also had to manually set DNS search settings due to an incompatibility with McAfee Endpoint Security before we could connect to other hosts on our internal network ([related github issue](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1976)).  VMWare had nothing to do with our issues in the end.  The container I'm working with right now is based on microsoft/windowsservercore, but I've been able to run nanoserver samples as well.